# Is there a way to do a Count If or Count Where within .Net Datacolumn Expression Properties?

Tags: .net, expression, datacolumn

I am using a reporting tool that allows me to use .Net Data Column Expression Properties to create calculated fields / headers. I am trying to create a calculated field that will tell me what percent of records have sales > $100.

-One of the headers I have creates a sales summary using sum(sales) which calculates a total of all sales.

-Another column I have runs a count on the number of records count(recordid).

-I can also create a column called STATUS using an IF statement to show if the record has a sales total greater than 100 by using IIF(SALES>100, 1, 0) will display a 1 if the sales are greater than 100 or a 0 if not

But so far I cannot figure out how to count the number of records with sales > 100. If I run a simple sum(STATUS) I get an error stating: Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.

How can I accomplish my goal of creating a column with a percent of sales above $100?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the code you're currently using?

Comment: The code I am using that is causing an error is: sum(STATUS) the column status is generated by: IIF(SALES>100, 1, 0)